# how i can check all checkboxes watin

Tags: browser, checkbox, watin, checked

I want to get all check boxes in page checked.

How to select all check boxes and enable all ?

```
var chk = browser.checkboxes.where(x => x.id("test string"));
```

Comment: thanks tharindu for edit my question

Comment: i solve myself. use this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach.

```
'
//Getting the count of the check boxes on the page.

int countOfCheckBox = browser.CheckBoxes.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < countOfCheckBox; i++)
{
    browser.CheckBoxes[i].Checked = true;
}
'
```